# Apache HTTPD server errors on start up, with no discernable error message

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I'm running Oracle Linux 7.8 on an HVM ec2 instance (t3.micro).  I've installed the latest HTTPD from the CodeIT repo, (2.4.43), and did a basic httpd.conf setup, w/ just one VirtualHost definition, for now.

When I run:

```
[oracle@nits-idp ~]$ sudo systemctl start httpd.service
```

I get:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So, I run:

```
[oracle@nits-idp ~]$ sudo systemctl status -l httpd.service
```

And I get:

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-07-26 19:47:14 EDT; 2min 6s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 6000 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 6000 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Reading configuration..."

Jul 26 19:47:14 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 26 19:47:14 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 26 19:47:14 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 26 19:47:14 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jul 26 19:47:14 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

And, finally:

```
[oracle@nits-idp ~]$ sudo journalctl -xe
```

returns:

```
Jul 26 19:49:20 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com sudo[6107]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by orac
Jul 26 19:49:20 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com sudo[6107]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 26 19:50:01 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of root.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 26 19:50:01 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com systemd[1]: Started Session 10 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-10.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-10.scope has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 26 19:50:01 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com CROND[6143]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 26 19:50:01 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of root.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down.
Jul 26 19:50:41 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com sudo[6183]:   oracle : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/oracle ; USER=root ; COMMAN
Jul 26 19:50:41 nits-idp.nitssolutions.com sudo[6183]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by orac
lines 2615-2641/2641 (END)
```

So, reading through this, I don't see the actual error.  I have no idea how to fix this, because I don't know the problem.

Help?

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: I was so wrapped up w/ the systemctl status and journalctl output, I forgot to look in /var/log/httpd/ logs.  That fixed it, thanks!  (I was using the wrong SSL cert.)  All good now.  If you want the reputation, please reply with an answer, and I'll upvote it and accept it.